# Pinterest - PHP : Publish an image

Tags: php, pinterest

I want my site able to publish pictures on my Pinterest.
I found this API PHP : https://github.com/kellan/pinterest.api.php

In order to authenticate, I've to get client_id, client_secret, username and password :

```
fetch_access_token($client_id, $client_secret, $username, $password)
```

But, I can't find my client secret. 
Do you know where it is ?
Username & password are those I use for connexion to my board ?
I don't really understand connexion...
https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/signature/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can register the client id from [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/manage/)

there is an option for Signature Tester on that page, once you click in there you will see the client_secret